# Spring JMS with Atomikos, poolsize and concurrent consumers

Tags: java, spring, atomikos

Can someone explain the semantic differences between the poolsize of a Atomikos connection factory, the pool size of the nested connection factory and concurrent consumers of a JMS Container?

Consider the following Spring config:

```
// ActiveMq vendor-specific Connection Factory
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory activeMQXAConnectionFactoryBean() {
    ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory xaCF = new ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
    xaCF.setMaxThreadPoolSize(10);
    return xaCF;
}

// Wrap it in an Atomikos ConnectionFactory
@Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
public ConnectionFactory atomikosConnectionFactoryBean(ConnectionFactory activeMQXAConnectionFactoryBean) {
    AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean atomikosCF = new AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean();
    atomikosCF.setUniqueResourceName("amq1");
    atomikosCF.setXaConnectionFactory(xaConnectionFactory);
    atomikosCF.setPoolSize(10);
    return atomikosCF;
}

// wire it into Spring's MessageListenerContainer
@Bean
public MessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer (ConnectionFactory atomikosConnectionFactoryBean) {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer mlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    mlc.setConnectionFactory(atomikosConnectionFactoryBean);
    mlc.setConcurrency("3-10");
    return mlc;
}
```

Can someone explain how the three settings affect JMS connections? For example should the poolsize of the connection factories here always be the same? What happens if they are not the same?

Comment: Did you figure out how these are related. I am facing a strange issue where despite having 10 concurrent consumers, only one is able to consume from the queue at anytime and this happens only when enabling Atomikos 2 PC.